# Using Disco Diffusion V5.2 - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, disco

I'm trying to run a few keyframe prompts for an animation test, however after the run starts and a haze based image forms, it only completes the first few passes and then hits me with this:

```
Seed used: 1412665177
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-95fd5446980a> in <module>()
    171 torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    172 try:
--> 173     do_run()
    174 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    175     pass

<ipython-input-8-f0c50060b30a> in do_run()
    366           else:
    367             img_0 = cv2.imread('prevFrame.png')
--> 368           center = (1*img_0.shape[1]//2, 1*img_0.shape[0]//2)
    369           trans_mat = np.float32(
    370               [[1, 0, translation_x],

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

So far I've not been able to figure it out through normal StackOverflow answers.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue: My prompts looked like this, divided by so many (""). So I strung the prompt together using the commas and less (""):
\
```0:["A beautiful ultradetailed painting of a single moon setting behind a mountain", "Joe Sorren", "J. Frederick Smith", "4k", "trending on artstation:3", "Aerial Photography", "Ultrawide lens", "People:-2", "Dof:-1", "blur:-1"],```
\

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the issue: My prompts looked like this, divided by so many (""). So I strung the prompt together using the commas and less (""):

`0:["A beautiful ultradetailed painting of a single moon setting behind a mountain", "Joe Sorren", "J. Frederick Smith", "4k", "trending on artstation:3", "Aerial Photography", "Ultrawide lens", "People:-2", "Dof:-1", "blur:-1"],`

\ TO THIS > \

`0:["A beautiful ultradetailed painting of a single moon setting behind a mountain, Joe Sorren, J. Frederick Smith, 4k, trending on artstation:3", "Aerial Photography", "Ultrawide lens", "People:-2", "Dof:-1", "blur:-1"],`

Now it runs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).